# See node properties in devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the devtools console, I would like to know if there is the possibilty to get the node properties, in a tree, like common objects.

Because it just returns the node content:

[image]

Comment: Use `dir(node)`

Comment: thank you! It is what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wOxxOm said, use `dir(node)`

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#dirobject